# Angular 5 Universal exclude path from rendering on server

Tags: javascript, angular, universal

Are there any way I can force only browser rendering of particular path for Angular 5 universal app?
I have following routes in app.module.shared.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [
        ......
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'auth-callback', component: AuthCallbackComponent},
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }        
        ]
        )
    ],
    providers: []
})
```

And I want **mysite.com/auth-callback** be only render in browser, not on server-side.
Thanks for any help, failed to find any helping info.

Comment: have you solve this ?

Comment: Not really. Actually it was a proof of concept test project and it was switched to React at the end.
Probably checking if window variable is undefined inside that component can help you somehow

Comment: You can use `isPlatformBrowser(platformId)` to check if it is browser / server. If you look for server you can use `isPlatformServer(this.platformId)`. They are a part of: `import {isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer} from '@angular/common';`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such yet, you place api folder in angular 2 root.. if you do such this, there will conflict between Angular2/4/5 route with api routes...

So, whether use sub-domain or put angular and api code in different directories..

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to load browser and server with route specific.

In your `server.ts` you need specify the routes like below.

```
  let routesPath = ['/invite', '/invite/**','/lm', '/dashboard', '/dashboard/**', '/public/**', '/public', '/pre'];
  server.get(routesPath, (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req);
    res.sendFile(distFolder + '/index.html');
  });
```

then update your server.ts

```
  let routesPath = ['/invite', '/invite/**','/lm', '/dashboard', '/dashboard/**', '/public/**', '/public', '/pre'];
  server.get(routesPath, (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req);
    res.sendFile(distFolder + '/index.html');
  });

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
```

You see in above code there is two different `server.get()`. First one will load browser. All route mentioned in `routesPath` will show normal browser mode.

The second one is all regular routes that will render as SSR.

---

I know its too late to answer but I hope it helps somebody reaching this question.